# Fetch in Angular2

Tags: angular

What is the proper way to use fetch here? Right now my app is loading the JSON in the background (I can see it in Chrome's developer tools) but this.games is undefined after execution and I can't figure out why. I'm assuming I'm returning the data wrong.

Right now I have this in my app.ts

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, Pipe} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { Game } from './game/game';
import { API } from './services/API';
@Component({    
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    {{games}}
            `,
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Game]
})
export class App {
    games: any;
    constructor(api: API) { 
        api.fetchGames().then(function(json){
            this.games = json;
        });
    };


}
bootstrap(App, [API]);
```

and my API.ts:

```
declare var Zone, fetch, Request;
export class API {
    data: any;
    fetchGames() {
        return fetch('http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=11%2F5%2F2015',{mode:'no-cors'})
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage Services in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624840/how-to-manage-services-in-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33586965/916450). The problem is in scope ('this') - 'this' inside promise callback is not the class. The simplest es6 solution is to change to [es6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, Pipe, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import { Game } from './game/game';
  import { API } from './services/API';
  import {NgZone} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({    
selector: 'app',
template: `
Hello
<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
<div *ng-for="#game of games" class = "game">
     //layout
</div>
`,
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Game],

 })
export class App {
data: any;
api: API;
games: Game[];

constructor(api:API) { 
    this.api = api;
    this.games = [];  
  api.fetchGames().then((response) => { //es6 arrow function will preserve class' 'this'
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
        var gamesTemp = [];
        this.teams = this.data.resultSets[1].rowSet;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.teams.length - 1; i += 2) {
            //manipulate            
        }
        this.games = gamesTemp;
        console.log(this.games);
    });
```