# Update angular2 View/global variable with data inside a promise

Tags: javascript, angular

Im using fetch to get data from an external API like this and it is printing to the console correctly.  But this.games doesn't update in the global scope so the view isn't updating.  How can I update the global gams variable with the data from within the promise once the fetch has returned :

```
  import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, Pipe, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import { Game } from './game/game';
  import { API } from './services/API';
  import {NgZone} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({    
selector: 'app',
template: `
Hello
<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
<div *ng-for="#game of games" class = "game">
     //layout
</div>
`,
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Game],

 })
export class App {
data: any;
api: API;
games: Game[];

constructor(api:API) { 
    this.api = api;
    this.games = [];  
  api.fetchGames().then(function(response) {
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
        var gamesTemp = [];
        this.teams = this.data.resultSets[1].rowSet;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.teams.length - 1; i += 2) {
            //manipulate            
        }
        this.games = gamesTemp;
        console.log(this.games);
    });
```

and this it the fetchGames method:

```
 fetchGames() {

    return fetch('http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=11%2F5%2F2015')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a scope (`this`) problem. Your `this` inside the callback is not your class! The simplest solution is to use [es6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
 import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, Pipe, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import { Game } from './game/game';
  import { API } from './services/API';
  import {NgZone} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({    
selector: 'app',
template: `
Hello
<button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
<div *ng-for="#game of games" class = "game">
     //layout
</div>
`,
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Game],

 })
export class App {
data: any;
api: API;
games: Game[];

constructor(api:API) { 
    this.api = api;
    this.games = [];  
  api.fetchGames().then((response) => { //es6 arrow function was meant to solve this problem!
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
        var gamesTemp = [];
        this.teams = this.data.resultSets[1].rowSet;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.teams.length - 1; i += 2) {
            //manipulate            
        }
        this.games = gamesTemp;
        console.log(this.games);
    });
```